# Deluge crashes at raspberry pi after while

Tags: raspbian, deluge

I have a raspberry pi which runs deluge. I used it like 2 months without any problem. However it started to carshing after i run it.

I don't know to how i can reach to crash info. So if you can tell me that how i can reach to 
crash info or something like system log i can provide more details to you for this problem.

edit:
i think the crash has a relation with the maximum connections or speed. while i set it connection number 1 it does not crash. also while i have low speed because of the low connection number, speed can have a relation with crash too.

Comment: Have you started it from a terminal? Most cases it will show some output and maybe Deluge has a --debug switch you can add to the command.

Comment: yes i started it from terminal via secure shell. but there are no output.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the solution. i erased the downloading files which are stuck at past. also i deleted the backups of torrents watch files.

briefly i deleted all files with related to my previous torrents.

Answer (score 1):

I found adding a swap file fixed this problem.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/

Comment: What makes you think it is related to a memory problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the deletion of files but it only worked for a while and the problem returned.

I eventually dumped Deluge and installed Transmission. So far it has not failed in anyway and I am beginning to feel confident enough with it to let it run without any supervision -- something I could never do with Deluge